# Unable to apply CSS on View HTML to PDF Conversion MVC Core

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core-mvc

I am not sure what's slipping away, tried all the articles around internet but unable to resolve the css, finally kept the CSS inline with the HTML to check but no Success.

Rendered the view and converted the view to HTML, and parsed the same but the css are not getting applied. Please advice.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Template Preview</title>
</head>

<body style="background: rgb(204,204,204);">
    <!-- /.container -->
    <div class="MainContainer">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            

<style>
    @media print {
    body {
        height: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border-top: none;
    }
}

@page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 0;
}

</style>
<page size="A4" style="background: white;display: block;margin: 0 auto;width: 21cm;height: 29.7cm;">
    <header>
        <div style="width: 100%;height: 125px;position: relative;">
            <img style="width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/monarch.png" alt="headerbgimg" />
            <div style="position: absolute;left: 20px;top: 5px;display: flex;flex-direction: column;">
                <div style="font-size: large;font-weight: bold;color: white;text-transform: uppercase;letter-spacing: 1px;">
                    <h2>Company Name</h2>
                </div>
                <span style="font-size: large;font-weight: bold;color: black;text-transform: uppercase;letter-spacing: 1px;">Header Text</span>
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute;right: 5px;top: 5px;width: 140px;height: 120px;">
                <img style="margin-left: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;height: 100%;width: 100%;" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/monarch.png" alt="companyLogo" />
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <div style="position: relative;width: 100%;height: 350px;">
            <div style="position: absolute;display: flex;flex-direction: column;left: 10px;top: 5px;">
                <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">13 September 2020</p>
                <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Travel Limited UK</p>
                <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Valid Untill 15 September 2020</p>
                <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><b>DEPARTURE DATE: </b>15 September 2020</p>
                <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><b>TOTAL NUMBER TRAVELLERS: </b>10</p>
                <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><b>NUMBER OF DAYS: </b>3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</page>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Action Method to show PDF on Browser**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPDF()
    {
        MemoryStream msPDF = new MemoryStream(await ParsePDFDocument());
        return new FileStreamResult(msPDF, "application/pdf");
    }

public async Task<byte[]> ParsePDFDocument()
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        byte[] result = null;

        #region HTML

        DummyData dummyData = new DummyData()
        {
            CompanyName = "Company Name.",
            HeaderText = "Header Text",

            ItineraryDate = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString(),
            TravelCompanyName = "Travel Limited UK",
            ValidityPeriod = "Valid Untill " + DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToLongDateString(),
            TravellersCount = 10,
            DaysCount = 3,
            DepartureDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToLongDateString(),

            ItineraryCode = "DS_001",
            EmailAddress = "ABC@XYZ.COM",
            Telephone = "+91 1234 123 123"
        };
            #endregion
//This will parse the cshtml view and give the HTML string
        var viewHtml = await this.RenderViewAsync<DummyData>("Index", dummyData);

        List<string> cssFiles = new List<string>();

        cssFiles.Add("NewStyle.css");

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
            writer.CloseStream = false;
            document.Open();
            HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
            htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

            ICSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);
            cssFiles.ForEach(i => cssResolver.AddCssFile(Path.Combine(hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "lib\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\" + i), true));

            IPipeline pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer)));
            XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
            XMLParser xmlParser = new XMLParser(worker);

            xmlParser.Parse(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(viewHtml)));

            document.Close();

            result = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you cannot apply CSS is because you did not successfully obtain the path of the sub-files under the folder "lib\bootstrap\dist\css\".

Here is a demo that can successfully obtain the path,try to change your code like this:

```
List<string> cssFiles = new List<string>();
cssFiles.Add("NewStyle.css");
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "lib\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\"));
//your code
ICSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);
foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.css"))
    {
    cssResolver.AddCssFile(Path.Combine(hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "lib\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\" + file.Name), true);                              
     }
```

Hope this can help you.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for coming forward to help, but I am getting the same and just using only one CSS file here. Do i really required to add other files? I feel I probably missing something else on conversion. Can you please post your demo code so i can try from there?

Comment: If you just add a css file, you only need to use cssResolver.AddCssFile(Path.Combine(hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "lib\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.min.css" ), true);In addition, I want to say that iTextsharp and xmlworker are not compatible in .net core, so I suggest you use iText7.